# Use a machine to run scripts on another machine

Tags: python, linux

I have some Python scripts and a file that comprises several database connect strings on a machine. This machine is a scheduler it regularly run scripts.

However, due to the limited calculation resources, what I want to do is the scheduler machine regularly "inform" other machines to use their resources to run scripts stored on my scheduler. I cannot distribute scripts and files containing connection info to other machine.

Is there any Linux command or python module or third-party software can do this?

Comment: This is an opinion, obviously: [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org)